# Understanding React Behind The Scene

Tags: javascript, reference, scope, reactjs, this

Im trying to get my head around 'Components' in React.

I have a few questions so I thoughts I'd SO community is the best place to ask them.

1 - When we do this:

```
var foo = React.createClass ({
...
});
```

Console.log tells me that this is a constructor. So when we do `<foo />`, we are creating an instance (object) of foo, correct?

2 - Im particularly getting confused by `this`, here is the example:

```
var bar = React.createClass ({
    render = function () {
        if (this.props.xyz) {
          ...
        }
    }
});
```

Now `<bar />` is a child component of foo. When `bar` instance is instantiated, `this` should refer to 'bar', shouldn't it? Why is it still referencing `foo`?

3 - Suppose I created multiple instaces of `<foo />`. How do we store reference to each particular object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `Foo` is a component class, and `<Foo />` creates what's called a *React element*, which is a lightweight description of which component class you want React to render; `<Foo />` actually gets turned into `React.createElement(Foo)`, which returns a simple object. It does not actually create an instance at that time. React looks at these elements during its reconciliation phase and instantiates components that it needs to behind the scenes.

   See [React (Virtual) DOM Terminology](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/glossary.html) for more information about the terminology.
2. `Bar` is only a child component of `Foo` if `Foo` returns a React element describing `Bar` from its render method. In any case, `this` refers to the current `Bar` component, and `this.props.xyz` refers to the props of the current `Bar` component. For example, if you did

   ```
   var Foo = React.createClass ({
     render: function() {
       return <Bar xyz="test" />;
     }
   });
   ```

   Then inside `Bar`, `this.props.xyz` will be the value "test", which was passed to `Bar` (just like an argument to a function) from its parent, `Foo`.
3. You can use [refs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html) to access component instances if you *really* need to, but especially when beginning, I recommend against this. It's usually not the correct way to get things done in React, and you should only need to access component instances in relatively rare instances.

Comment: Thanks @MichelleTilley, could you elaborate on (3) (how to keep references or what design pattern to follow)?

Comment: @Kayote Take a look at the documentation linked in the answer to #3 and let me know if you have specific questions

Answer (score 0):

1. Correct. `foo` is like a constructor but under the scene it uses `React.createElement(foo, null)` when you type `<foo />`.
2. `this` is gonna refer to the instance of `bar` in this case, not the constructor.
3. To keep multiple instances of `foo`, just keep them in variables like usual.

```js
    a = React.createElement(foo, null); //or a = <foo />
    b = React.createElement(foo, null); //or b = <foo />
```

PS: Convention is to `CamelCase` the class names (`foo` becomes `Foo`)